# Dynamically loading custom fonts in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uifont

Can you dynamically load custom fonts in iOS similar to how you do in Javascript?

I have seen few questions about this but they are quite outdated or don't really answer the question.

I don't want to add a font to my application/register it in the info.plist. I want to be able to dynamically load a custom new font that is not in my library then use it within my app.

Comment: Hi, did you try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40508041/how-to-load-a-custom-font-in-ios-app-from-a-file-not-from-info-plist ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only fonts you can *download* dynamically and use are Apple's own fonts. You can *include* a font and use it, and you can even make it available to other apps ("font provider"), but you cannot download an arbitrary font. That would be a security hole and Apple doesn't permit it.